# Expandable table view cell (FAQ style)

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have an FAQ style table view where each cell contains 2 UILabels - one for the question and one for the answer. For now, the question and the answer are shown on viewDidLoad(). Using the didSelectRowAt() method, I thought I could hide the answer UILabel when the cell is clicked but it doesn't seem to be working. Nothing changes on tapping the cell.

[image: FAQ Table View Cell]

Code:

```
class FAQsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var faqsTableView: UITableView!
    
    struct faqStructure {
        let question: String
        let answer: String
    }
    
    var faqsArray: [faqStructure] = []
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        
        faqsTableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        faqsTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 600
        faqQuery()
    }
    
    @IBAction func dismiss(_ sender: UIButton) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    func faqQuery() {
        let faqsDB = Database.database().reference().child("FAQs")
        faqsDB.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            self.faqsArray.removeAll()
            for child in snapshot.children {
                let faqSnapshot = child as! DataSnapshot
                let faqQuestion = faqSnapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "Question").value as! String
                let faqAnswer = faqSnapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "Answer").value as! String
                self.faqsArray.append(.init(question: faqQuestion, answer: faqAnswer))
                self.faqsTableView.reloadData()
            }
        })
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return faqsArray.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let faqItem = faqsTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FAQ Cell") as! FAQsItemCell
        faqItem.questionLabel.text = faqsArray[indexPath.row].question
        faqItem.answerLabel.text = faqsArray[indexPath.row].answer
        
        return faqItem
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let faqItem = faqsTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FAQ Cell") as! FAQsItemCell
        faqItem.answerLabel.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a really good article that got it working perfectly with minimal changes to my code!

https://medium.com/@alexiscreuzot/expanding-uitableview-cells-using-only-constraints-in-swift-f40b13206ea3

In the code for the TableViewItemCell, the key is to have a boolean which indicates whether the cell is expanded or not:

```
class FAQExpandableItem {
    var question: String
    var answer: String
    var isExpanded: Bool
    
    init(question: String, answer: String) {
        self.question = question
        self.answer = answer
        self.isExpanded = false
    }
}

class FAQsItemCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var questionLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var answerLabel: UILabel!
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
    
    func set(content: FAQExpandableItem) {
        self.questionLabel.text = content.question
        self.answerLabel.text = content.isExpanded ? content.answer : ""
    }
}
```

And then in the ViewController, we use the didSelectRowAt method to toggle this boolean:

```
class FAQsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var faqsTableView: UITableView!
    
    struct faqStructure {
        let question: String
        let answer: String
    }
    
    var faqsArray: [faqStructure] = []
    var faqData = [FAQExpandableItem]()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        faqsTableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        faqsTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 600
        faqQuery()
    }
    
    @IBAction func dismiss(_ sender: UIButton) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    func faqQuery() {
        let faqsDB = Database.database().reference().child("FAQs")
        faqsDB.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            self.faqsArray.removeAll()
            for child in snapshot.children {
                let faqSnapshot = child as! DataSnapshot
                let faqQuestion = faqSnapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "Question").value as! String
                let faqAnswer = faqSnapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "Answer").value as! String
                self.faqData.append(FAQExpandableItem(question: faqQuestion, answer: faqAnswer))
                self.faqsTableView.reloadData()
            }
        })
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return faqData.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let faqItem = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FAQ Cell", for: indexPath) as! FAQsItemCell
        faqItem.set(content: faqData[indexPath.row])
        return faqItem
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let content = faqData[indexPath.row]
        content.isExpanded = !content.isExpanded
        tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use section and row combination for expanding & collapsing behavior. It is quite effective. You can search Expandable Tableview on the internet for more details

Anyways, The issue is on your didselect method

Change this line

```
let faqItem = faqsTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FAQ Cell") as! FAQsItemCell
```

To

```
guard let faqItem = faqsTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? FAQsItemCell else { return }
```

/// Used guard for more safety

I believe hiding labels will not decrease your cell height, also you are not storing results (i.e hide/show state) so it will create an issue with dequeueReusableCell.